# How to make Azure SqlTrigger ignore previous changes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use SqlTrigger from Preview package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp

I'm doing outbox implementation, currently it's using timer trigger. Obviously I don't want it to publish all old messages. I found that it creates db table `[az_func].[GlobalState]` with 4 columns:

```
[UserFunctionID],[UserTableID],[LastSyncVersion],[LastAccessTime]
```

I understand 3 of them, but can't figure out how to calculate `UserFunctionId` .

I tried it locally on several different laptops it seems to be consistent for single laptop, but on each gives different results.

Answer (score 0):

- The `UserFunctionID` in the `[az_func].[GlobalState]` table is an internal identifier generated by the Azure Functions runtime and is not something that you can manually calculate or provide. It is used by the runtime to track the state of the function and associate it with the corresponding row in the table.
- You can manually update the `LastSyncVersion` value in the `[az_func].[GlobalState]` table to a value higher than the maximum version of the changes you want to skip. You can use a SQL query to update the value.

```cs
UPDATE [az_func].[GlobalState]
SET [LastSyncVersion] = <new_version>
WHERE [UserFunctionID] = '<your_user_function_id>'
```

Please refer this for more [information.](https://dev.to/willvelida/working-with-azure-sql-triggers-in-azure-functions-1op4)

**Second approach:**

UserFunctionID column generates based on the machine’s MAC address and a process-specific identifier. it will be different on each machine and for each instance of the function.

here is my Physical machine address:
[image]

```cs
using System;
using System.Management;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string userFunctionID = GetUserFunctionID();
        Console.WriteLine(userFunctionID);
    }

    public static string GetUserFunctionID()
    {
        string macAddress = GetMacAddress();
        int processId = Environment.ProcessId;

        string userFunctionID = $"{macAddress}-{processId}";
        return userFunctionID;
    }

    private static string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddress = string.Empty;
        ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection managementObjects = managementClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjects)
        {
            if ((bool)managementObject["IPEnabled"])
            {
                macAddress = managementObject["MacAddress"].ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddress.Replace(":", "");
    }
}
```

Expected output looks like: `001122334455-1234`
[image]

**1234** is the ID of the function and the machine address is `00:11:22:33:44:55`